# when using htaccess all the internal links are changed

Tags: .htaccess

i want to change my website urls exemple www.mysite.com/about.php to www.mysite.com/about/

i'm using this code in my htaccess file

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>
```

i tried this one too

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

it works but all the page content becomes inside the /about/ its like i created a folder that does not exist so all the internal links are changed , if i have a link to post.php it goes to /about/post.php

all the included pages are not working too such as css and images

sorry my english isn't so good  .

Answer (score 0):

i finally found what i wanted ,i used this meta tag in the header section

```
`<base href="http://localhost/mysite/" />`
```

now everything works

ps: don't use localehost on webhost